# Elastic search edge ngram not returning all expected results

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am having a hard time in finding the elastic search query unexpected results. Indexed the following documents into elastic search.

```
{
"group": "J00-I99", codes: [
   { "id": "J15", "description": "hello world" },
   { "id": "J15.0", "description": "test one world" },
   { "id": "J15.1", "description": "test two world J15.0" },
   { "id": "J15.2", "description": "test two three world J15" },
   { "id": "J15.3", "description": "hello world J18 " },
    ............................ // Similar records here
   { "id": "J15.9", "description": "hello world new" },
   { "id": "J16.0", "description": "new description" }
]
}
```

Here my aim is to implement autocomplete functionality and for that I used n-gram approach. I don't want to use complete suggester approach.

Currently I am stuck with two issues:

1. Search query (both id and description fields ) : J15

Expected result: All the above results which includes J15
Actual result: Getting only few results (J15.0, J15.1, J15.8)

2. Search query (both id and description fields ) : test two

Expected result:

```
{ "id": "J15.1", "description": "test two world J15.0" },
{ "id": "J15.2", "description": "test two three world J15" },
```

Actual Result:

```
   { "id": "J15.0", "description": "test one world" },
   { "id": "J15.1", "description": "test two world J15.0" },
   { "id": "J15.2", "description": "test two three world J15" },
```

Then mapping is done like this.

```
           {

                settings: {
                    number_of_shards: 1,
                    analysis: {
                        filter: {
                            ngram_filter: {
                                type: 'edge_ngram',
                                min_gram: 2,
                                max_gram: 20
                            }
                        },
                        analyzer: {
                            ngram_analyzer: {
                                type: 'custom',
                                tokenizer: 'standard',
                                filter: [
                                    'lowercase', 'ngram_filter'
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                mappings: {
                    properties: {
                        group: {
                            type: 'text'
                        },
                        codes: {
                            type: 'nested',
                            properties: {
                                id: {
                                    type: 'text',
                                    analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                                    search_analyzer: 'standard'
                                },
                                description: {
                                    type: 'text',
                                    analyzer: 'ngram_analyzer',
                                    search_analyzer: 'standard'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Search Query:

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "codes"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "codes",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "codes.description": "J15"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "codes.id": "J15"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Document index will be large in size. Here only sample data mentioned.

For the second issue, can i use multi_match with AND operator like the below?

```
GET myindex/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "excludes": [
      "codes"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "codes",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                    "query": "J15",
                    "fields": ["codes.id", "codes.description"],
                    "operator": and
                }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated as I am having hard time in fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another answer, as its a different issue and first answer was focused on first issue.

Issue is that your second query `test two` returns `test one world` as well as while indexing you are using the `ngram_analyzer` which is using **the standard analyzer which split the text on white-spaces** and again your search analyzer is `standard` so if you use the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) on your indexed doc and search term, you will see it matches the tokens:

```
{
   "text" : "test one world",
   "analyzer" : "standard"
}
```

**And generated tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "test",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "one",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "world",
            "start_offset": 9,
            "end_offset": 14,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

**And for your search term `test two`**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "test",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "two",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**As you can see `test` token was present in your document hence you get that search result. and it can be solved by using the AND operator in the query as shown below**

**Search query**

```
{
    "_source": {
        "excludes": [
            "codes"
        ]
    },
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "codes",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "test two",
                            "fields": [
                                "codes.id",
                                "codes.description"
                            ],
                            "operator" :"AND"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

**And search results**

```
 "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 2
                                    },
                                    "_score": 2.6901608,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15.1",
                                        "description": "test two world J15.0"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 3
                                    },
                                    "_score": 2.561376,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15.2",
                                        "description": "test two three world J15"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: i got the problem but what i was looking for is a solution.. i have added in the descripton like can i use multi_match with AND operator. Could you have a look into that (last section)

Comment: but I can't see your query, it should work, if you can add your query, I will work on that to make it work

Comment: its already there in the below "For the second issue, can i use multi_match with AND operator like the below?" Section. Please see.

Comment: Just tried that and it works, please see the update

Comment: Yes, def with any doubt, you can see its returning the expected search result :) i hv used your mapping and data

Comment: thanks upvoted, could you please clarify the doubt which i have commented innthe other answer chat section?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was that by default `inner_hits` returns only 3 matching docs as mentioned in [this official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html),

> size
>
> The maximum number of hits to return per inner_hits. **By default the
> top three matching hits are returned.**

simply add `size` param in your inner_hits to get all the search results.

```
  "inner_hits": {
                "size": 10 // note this
            }
```

**Tried this on your sample data and see the search result for your first query which was returning only 3 search results**

**First query search result**

```
   "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 2
                                    },
                                    "_score": 1.8687118,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15.1",
                                        "description": "test two world J15.0"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 3
                                    },
                                    "_score": 1.7934312,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15.2",
                                        "description": "test two three world J15"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 0
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.29618382,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15",
                                        "description": "hello world"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 1
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.29618382,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15.0",
                                        "description": "test one world"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 4
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.29618382,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15.3",
                                        "description": "hello world J18 "
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index": "myindexedge64170045",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_nested": {
                                        "field": "codes",
                                        "offset": 5
                                    },
                                    "_score": 0.29618382,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "id": "J15.9",
                                        "description": "hello world new"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks.could you please help me in the second issue mentioned?

Comment: @Vishnu sure, did you verify your first query is working or not?

Comment: @opster-elastic-search-ninja yes i have verified by adding size. Few queries like, since the volume of data is high, can i add size more than 100? Also instead of fetching _source how can i add doc value fields? Is it recommended?

Comment: Actually these points are not really for another s.o question.. so could you please explain it here, if you don't mind..

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "group": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "codes": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "group": "J00-I99", 
    "codes": [
        {
            "id": "J15",
            "description": "hello world"
        },
        {
            "id": "J15.0",
            "description": "test one world"
        },
        {
            "id": "J15.1",
            "description": "test two world J15.0"
        },
        {
            "id": "J15.2",
            "description": "test two three world J15"
        },
        {
            "id": "J15.3",
            "description": "hello world J18 "
        },
        {
            "id": "J15.9",
            "description": "hello world new"
        },
        {
            "id": "J16.0",
            "description": "new description"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
    "_source": {
        "excludes": [
            "codes"
        ]
    },
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "codes",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "codes.description": "J15"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "codes.id": "J15"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "must": {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "test two",
                            "fields": [
                                "codes.id",
                                "codes.description"
                            ],
                            "type": "phrase"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"inner_hits": {
          "codes": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 3.2227304,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64170045",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "codes",
                    "offset": 3
                  },
                  "_score": 3.2227304,
                  "_source": {
                    "id": "J15.2",
                    "description": "test two three world J15"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "stof_64170045",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "codes",
                    "offset": 2
                  },
                  "_score": 2.0622847,
                  "_source": {
                    "id": "J15.1",
                    "description": "test two world J15.0"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: please see my answer, here root cause was different, his index settings are correct, only due to default size limit of 3, OP was not getting all the search results.

Comment: @bhavya could you please explain a bit about the changes you made. It would be really helpful!

Comment: @Vishnu is the search result given in my answer, match to your expected result ?

Comment: @bhavya no i could not be able to match with my expected result. The issue is as said by opster. Inner hits size